# How do I develop a vehicle design system for a tabletop roleplaying game (examples include Traveller, Striker, and Fire Fusion& Steel)?

Tags: game-design, traveller

**How do I develop a crunchy simulationist vehicle design system for a tabletop roleplaying game (examples include Traveller, Striker, and Fire Fusion& Steel)?**

How do I develop a vehicle design system?

I'm looking for recommendations for structuring my research from ttrpg designers who have experience with this, and also for useful suggestions ttrpg enthusiasts may have.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't do really do recommendations/suggestions like this; "how do I design a complex subsystem in a game" is just too large a question for our site. You're probably better going to a forum (ideally one focused on the specific game you're interested in) and using a thread there to workshop mechanics.